# AS3 continuous timer?

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

If I understand this correctly, most timer examples I've seen in AS3 are limited by a certain number of occurrences.  Such as:

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 2);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, blah);
    timer.start();

function blah(e:TimerEvent):void{
    trace("Times Fired: " + e.currentTarget.currentCount);
     trace("Time Delayed: " + e.currentTarget.delay);
}
```

Where it would fire twice (again, if I interpreted this correctly)

So if what I assumed is true, is there a way to make a timer where it would continuously keep track of time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Omitting the 2nd argument in the `Timer` constructor (or setting it to `0`) will make the timer event fire infinitely:

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
```